# sed stdin behaviour

Tags: sed, aix

Using sed for a direct stdin treatment of data, I expect that a line is treated after the *enter*.
This is what happens when I test on CygWin or Linux but on my AIX, a second *new line* is needed to treat the line. I tried with the `-u` flag to avoid buffer latency without modification in behaviour. Is there an option or parameter to let the POSIX AIX `sed` work like on other OSs?

Example:

```
> sed -u '=;l;s/foo/bar/'
like my foo            (enter)
but not the lazy dog   (enter)
1                      (stdout)
like my foo$           (stdout)
like my bar            (stdout)
```

Comment: This is more than likely a quality of your line discipline than `sed`'s deal. Use the `l` command to get a good look at what it sees as input.

Comment: adapt the post to show the stream. line seems ok, this is just the need of a second line like a buffer behaviour and only on my AIX (that use posix sed)

Comment: Its not though - your terminal is doing something - icr nl? opost? what's definitely missing there is the `\r`. maybe prime it : `echo | sed ... - /dev/tty`. That wont get you the `\r`, but it might offset the line delay. This shouldn't be a problem in `stty raw` mode - but in that case you might have to specially handle `\r` `\n`.

Comment: `\r` appear on windows system, not unix by default. The `-` in `sed ... - /dev` is also not valid on my/a AIX/KSH (or bash)

Comment: The `\r` appears on a windows system due to crlf line endings. But they will also appear on a linux system if you type one - like when you press `return` to a get a `\n`ewline. That's handled by your terminal driver's line discipline. If `sed` doesn't understand the `-` for stdin does it instead understand `/dev/stdin` or `/dev/fd/0`?

Comment: unfortunatelly no. A cat > file should show the same content, no ?

Comment: Are you running the same version of `sed` on each OS?

Comment: no. I also test a sed pipe sed and the problem is esxtended (1 extra line needed on second sed). Seems that this is 'interactive' sed on my AIX that use a kind of buffer.